# How do I test for the CONNECT permission on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have some database accounts that were created with a script but for some reason on some systems it lacks the connect permission and are disabled.  Once applied it works.  I want to check for this on systems for the future.  How can I check the user has the CONNECT permission?  Thank you.

Comment: Well, try to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @SQLSoldier on Twitter I found the answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.database_principals dprinc
    INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions dperm
    ON dprinc.principal_id = dperm.grantee_principal_id
WHERE dprinc.name = '<username>' AND dperm.permission_name = 'CONNECT'
```